# simple php meta redirect script not working

Tags: php

I have `http://mysite.com/go.php?site=http://somesite.com/main/?s=12&action=load`

```
<?php
$url = $_GET['site'];

echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=" . $url . "\">";
```

however, it takes me to `http://somesite.com/main/?s=12` which fails to load.

how to make it go to `http://somesite.com/main/?s=12&action=load`

Comment: Correction: there is no 'meta redirects' in PHP. This is silly HTML redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT]: New Solution**

This works like a charm. I tested on my machine.

```
$url = urldecode(substr(http_build_query($_GET),5));
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=" . $url . "\">";
```

**Old solution (not working)**
Change your code to this:

```
$url = $_GET['site'];
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;url=" . urlencode($url) . "\">";
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem: The URL itself is already not properly encoded.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `urlencode()` the  URL you  pass as the `site` variable *beforehand* (i.e. when creating the go.php link).

As a side note, if this is the only thing your page outputs, why not use

```
header("Location: ".$url);
```

?

It would issue a `302 Found` header to the browser, telling it to follow to the new location, instead of outputting HTML (which is broken anyway if output without a proper page structure).

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the parameter you are passing to the `site` parameter. You can do so by using `urlencode()` in PHP or `encodeURI()` in javascript.

So that makes it something like:

```
http://mysite.com/go.php?site=http%3a%2f%2fsomesite.com%2fmain%2f%3fs%3d12%26action%3dload
```

Now in PHP, you can do:

```
<?php
header("Location: ".$_GET['site']);
?>
```